# Проблема с else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Пишу игру на пайтоне (про казино). В одном моменте игрок должен выбрать какое число ему выпадет (больше чем его ставка или меньше).

```
def play():
        print("Хорошо, начинаем играть, как думаешь, что выпадет?")
casinorandom = input('Больше или меньше? (<, >): ')
if casinorandom == ">":
        print("Окей, ты думаешь что выпадет больше.")
        random1 = random.randint(1, int(playvalue) + 50)
        if int(random1) < int(playvalue):
            print('Лол, ты всрал свои money')
        wait(500)
        fii.write(int(playcount) + 1)
        lobby()
        else: # тот самый else с проблемой
            print('Гц, ты выйграл!!')
        wait(500)
        fii.write(int(playcount) + 1)
        fi.write(int(wincount) + 1)
        lobby()
```

IDLE пишет, что данный else не требуется (ошибка синтаксиса).

Comment: Расставьте правильно отступы/табуляции, в строках перед `else:`  должны быть отступы/табуляции

Comment: Да и до того с отступами полные непонятки. Логику исполнения невозможно понять.

Comment: Вы `else` пишете без `if`. После `if` идут вызовы функций, а только потом `else`. Вот и непонятно - к чему он привязан и когда должен выполниться.

Comment: "Ошибка синтаксиса" означает, что в коде допущена ошибка, которая делает выполнение кода невозможным. А совсем не то, что что-то там не требуется. Ну нужно выдумывать.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в том, что ты в некоторых местах не поставил tab (aka 4 пробела). Чтобы это исправить - вот, что я сделал

```
def play():
    print("Хорошо, начинаем играть, как думаешь, что выпадет?")
    casinorandom = input('Больше или меньше? (<, >): ')
    if casinorandom == ">":
        print("Окей, ты думаешь что выпадет больше.")
        random1 = random.randint(1, int(playvalue) + 50)
        if int(random1) < int(playvalue):
            print('Лол, ты всрал свои money')
            wait(500) # это я подвинул на tab
            fii.write(int(playcount) + 1) # это я подвинул на tab
            lobby() # это я подвинул на tab
        else: # тот самый else с проблемой
            print('Гц, ты выйграл!!')
            wait(500) # это я подвинул на tab
            fii.write(int(playcount) + 1) # это я подвинул на tab
            fi.write(int(wincount) + 1) # это я подвинул на tab
            lobby() # это я подвинул на tab
```

Почему не работает:
python вообще не понимает, что от него хотят, когда мы пишем так

```
if:
    действие
тут какая-та инфа 
else:
    действие
```

Чтобы это исправить, надо убрать это `тут какая-та инфа` или отодвинуть, чтобы было так

```
if:
    действие
    тут какая-та инфа 
else:
    действие
```